# Is this thing K-finite?

Tags: logic, category-theory, topos-theory

This is related to this question:

[Freyd's Geometric Finiteness : An Example Computation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/308302/freyds-geometric-finiteness-an-example-computation)

I've essentially reduced the problem to the following question:

Equip $\mathbb{N}$ with the discrete topology and let $P$ be the sheaf of germs of functions $f:\mathbb{N}\rightarrow\mathbb{N}$ such that $f(k)=0$ for all but finitely many $k\in\mathbb{N}$ and such that $f(k)\leq k$.  Is $P$ K-finite?

If anyone has an insight, I would appreciate it.  Also, I'm not sure if the logic tag is necessarily appropriate here, so feel free to remove it if it isn't.

Comment: Note that, on a discrete space, germs amount to just values at single points, so "$f(k)=0$ for all but finitely many $k\in\mathbb N$" is irrelevant in describing germs. On the other hand, imposing this finite-support requirement on *sections* would mean you don't have a sheaf but only a presheaf.  The associated sheaf would have as its sections all functions $\mathbb N\to\mathbb N$ with $(\forall k)\,f(k)\leq k$.

Comment: Yeah, I was still thinking about $Sh(\mathbb{R})$.  It's internally K-finite, though, since $Sh(\mathbb{N})$ is just a countable co-product of copies of $Sets$ and it's K-finite in each factor, right?

Answer (score 1):

Upon reflection, I want to retract this question.  It seems I've confused myself by confusing "internally K-finite" with "externally K-finite".  Internally it's clearly true that it is K-finite, and externally it's clearly not:  If we look at the subalgebra of $Sub_{Sh(\mathbb{N})}(P)$ that contains $\emptyset$ and is closed under adjoining singletons we'll only get the "bounded" subobjects.  It seems that in the paper referenced in the linked question, Freyd must have had "internally K-finite" in mind.